# Python class throwing: can't convert 'list' object to str implicitl

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

It doesn't appear I can access my fields `Database.query_stmt_list[i]` in Python 3.5.

**My code looks like:**

```
class Database():
    query_stmt_list = ['SELECT','INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE','FROM','WHERE']
    def __init__(self):
        self.query_stmt_list = Database.query_stmt_list
    def db_select(self, *selected_fields, **kwargs):
        self.selected_fields = selected_fields = list(selected_fields)
        self.table = (kwargs['table']
                      if 'table' in kwargs 
                      else selected_fields.pop())
        self.where_field = (kwargs['where_field']
                            if 'where_field' in kwargs
                            else selected_fields.pop())
        try:
            with self.db.cursor() as cursor:
                sql_tld_id_query = Database.query_stmt_list[0]+ selected_fields + Database.query_stmt_list[4] + table + Database.query_stmt_list[5] + where_field + '=' + 'www.website.com'
            print("sql_tld_id_query is {}".format(sql_tld_id_query))   
        except Exception as gatherid_err:
            print("exception was {}".format(gatherid_err))
            self.db.rollback()

#instantiate class/method       
dbclass = Database()
dbclass.set_db_setting('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'garbagedb')
dbclass.db_select(['id', 'name'], table='tld', where_field='name')
```

I get an error like:

> Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

**on line:**

```
sql_tld_id_query = Database.query_stmt_list[0]+ selected_fields + Database.query_stmt_list[4] + table + Database.query_stmt_list[5] + where_field + '=' + 'www.website.com'
```

**FULL STACK**:

```
$ python dbcrud.py 
connected to: garbagedb
exception was sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

What am I doing wrong here? Does anyone see what is going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: See updated above please

Comment: Always post the *full stack trace*, but likely, the problem is **exactly what it says**: You cannot convert a `list` to a `str` implicitely. Something in that line is actually a list, which you cannot `+` to a `str`

Comment: @Jshee:  you're swallowing the full stack trace in your "except" clause.  Use "import traceback" and "traceback.print_exc()" to print the whole thing.  For an even cruder debug attack, print out all terms used in that sql_tld_id_query line just before executing it-- that will show you that "selected_fields" is the problem.

Comment: where should i put traceback

Comment: Btw, I never `execute` it. Im trying to form the var `sql_tld_id_query`. Execution is currently commented out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to form a string on that line.  Rather than the term

```
selected_fields
```

which is a list, not a string, seems like you want

```
', '.join(selected_fields)
```

to form a proper comma separated, SQL-compliant listing of fields, yes?

```
sql_tld_id_query = Database.query_stmt_list[0]+ ', '.join(selected_fields) + Database.query_stmt_list[4] + table + Database.query_stmt_list[5] + where_field + '=' + 'www.website.com'
```

Comment: This throws an error of `exception was sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?  (You should do that for your original post as well.)